# Веб интерфейс логических связей

Tags: javascript, frontend, ui

Интересует такая вот вещь(не знаю как правильно называется, поэтому и пишу). Такой себе интерактивный интерфейс, где пользователь сам строит логику работы сервиса, перетаскивая на экране различные блоки, устанавливает между ними связи(в виде стрелок от блока к блоку) и пр. Что-то на подобие интерактивной блоксхемы. Видел такое в некоторых сервисах емаил рассылок и еще парочке других. 
Интересует вопрос - это все каждый пишет с нуля под свои нужды или же может есть какие-то готовые библиотеки или фреймворки. Ну и как такой интерфейс правильно называется.